# Calculating Percentage of Work done within a Library to display a smooth progress bar

Tags: mfc, progress-bar

I am creating a library, this library does huge amount of work. I am also creating a Evaluation Application what will display all the results calculated by the library.

Now, I need to create a progress bar in my Evaluation application to intimate the user that my library is doing some work and is not hanged.

I know how to create the progress bar, I also know that there should be a callback mechanism,  but the only thing i do not know is how to calculate the percentage of work done by the library, so as to display it in the progress bar.

The progress bar should be a smooth one and displaying the percentage of work done by the library.

I am using MFC to create Evaluation Application.

Help of any kind would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So are you saying that you can do everything except calculating a percentage? Do you have a measure of the total work and the work completed (or remaining)?

Comment: If you don't have a complete measure of the work, you will have to use a *marquee* style progress bar.

Comment: @RogerRowland: Yes i am saying exactly that. And I do not have the measure of total work and work completed. I need to know how to find this. 

So is it like we need to break the work done by library into stages? So if there are 10 stages required to do the complete work, after each stage is completed i will be moving my progress bar 10% ahead.
In this case there is a problem which i foresee (you can correct me if i am wrong). The problem is as and when the library grows, the number of stages will grow, and i need to change the percentage value by which the progress bar should be moving.

Comment: @rrirower: Marquee style progress bar gives me the feeling of being in a limbo. Its like will this ever stop ;). Jokes apart, If everything else fails I would be using this. But I am sure, guys here will help me out to figure out a way, since I have seen many progress bars which shows the real time progress of the work done.

Comment: Well, you can't do it without knowing the total amount of work. The only option you have is, as your library grows, you maintain an additional function through which you can query the total number of stages - maybe you already have this though because you need to actually *do* all the work, so how come you don't know when you will be finished?

Comment: @RogerRowland: Well in my library I still haven't introduced any stages as such, remember I still haven't created any progress bar.
However, I am not sure of the function you are talking about. I think I don't understand it. Could you please give a small example to make me understand. I am really sorry if I am being a naive.